# python django latitude longitude filter in queryset

Tags: python, django, geopy

I have a field like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
```

Lets say I have lat long value like

```
myval = (27.66469717424158, 85.30983049711507)
```

Here I want to find all the objects in `MyModel` which are less than 10 KM in distance from `myval`

I looked into `geopy` library. I think it is useful after I get the data from queryset.

How to achieve this ?